Exercise 4.9 from Oksendal, SDEs
In Oksendal, SDE with applications in the hint to Exercise 4.9 it is said that $\mathbb{P}(\tau_n>t)$ tends to one, as $n\longrightarrow\infty$, where $\tau_n$ is the first time an Ito process $X_t$ satisfies $|X_t|\ge n$. I am fine with all other parts of the exercise, but I am unable to prove this assertion. The sole assumptions are that $dX_t=u(t,\omega)dt+v(t,\omega)dB_t$, $\mathbb{P}(\int_0^t|u(s,\omega)|ds <\infty\text{ for all }t\ge 0)=1$ and $\mathbb{P}(\int_0^t v^2(s,\omega)ds <\infty\text{ for all }t\ge 0)=1$. $B_t$ is the Brownian motion and both $u$ and $v$ are adapted to it as usual. How should one proceed? Thanks.
EDIT: from a suggestion in the comment, the solution follows by considering that $X_t$ is continuous almost surely. However, it is still unclear whether the condition $\mathbb{P}(\int_0^t|u(s,\omega)|ds <\infty\text{ for all }t\ge 0)=1$, which is weaker than $\mathbb{P}(\int_0^\infty|u(s,\omega)|ds <\infty)=1$ under which I can prove the claim of a.s. continuity of $\int_0^tu(s,\omega)ds$ needed, suffices.

A typical sample path $s\mapsto X_s(\omega)$ is a continuous function of $s\ge 0$. In particular, $M_t(\omega):=\sup_{0\le s\le t}|X_s(\omega)|$ is finite for each $t>0$.

@JohnDawkins Thank you so much, using continuity I can derive the result. Oksendal does not state it explicitly in the definition at the beginning of Chap 4, but is an Ito process always assumed to be chosen as continuous? In particular, is $\int_0^t u dt$ always continuous in t with these assumptions? Oksendal only speaks explicitly of continuity of $\int_0^t v dB_t$... perhaps is it a standard result from analysis he is assuming?

Actually, I think it does follow. The usual proof of continuity of the integral for $u(\cdot,\omega)\in L^1(0,\infty)$ is actually stronger, as it proves uniform continuity of the integral above. Here we only need continuity for every $t$, so we can get away with less, in particular we do not need a simple function approximation on the half line, but only on sets $[0,t]$, so the simple functions can depend on $t$, having an upper-bound dependent on $t$ as well, through which we can define the $\delta=\delta(\epsilon,t)$ for the def of continuity at $t$.
